Google Analytics Tag in Flutter Web: Custom DataLayer Variable (customerID) Not Captured on Button Click
I'm working on a Flutter Web app and trying to dynamically push a customerID to the DataLayer for Google Analytics tracking when a button is clicked. Despite seeing the dataLayer object in the browser's console, Google Analytics isn't capturing the customerID.
My Code:
Pushing to DataLayer:
import 'dart:html' as html;

void trackCustomerID(String customerID) {
  html.window.dataLayer ??= [];
  html.window.dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'customerIDEvent',
    'customerID': customerID,
  });
}

Button:
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    trackCustomerID('12345'); // Example customer ID
  },
  child: Text('Click Me'),
)

What I've Tried:

Verified the Google Analytics script is correctly included in index.html.
Confirmed dataLayer exists in the browser console.
Debugged with console.log(window.dataLayer) but don't see the customerID update.

Question
How can I ensure Google Analytics captures the dynamically pushed customerID value from the DataLayer in a Flutter Web app?
